# How to archive the contents of a HTML page into 1 file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering how to save an HTML file and all dependencies into one file. Unlike an MHTML file, it won't cut it to change style.css to example.com/style.css. It needs to become:`<style>[css]</style>`

Would you do this by getting, for example, the CSS then creating the `<style>` tags in the `<head>` and pasting the style tags? What (if any) JS libraries would I use? Or should I use JQuery and AJAX?

**EDIT:**

I'm making a tool that can archive pages with CSS and JS inline. For Example, so you can archive data on a site before heading into a meeting, so you don't have to worry about a server being down, or the stats changing.

Comment: Can you provide context for why it is you are doing this?  It would be helpful; if the question includes your specific requirements, then the answers will be tailored to meet those requirements.

Comment: This sounds more like a task to do at the server.

Comment: @Teemu well if you have aceius.com and aceiuscorp.com, their different sites. Or if you use a 3rd party service that you don't have complete control over, this can't be done on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project and my solution involved a few parts:

- Have the intended css in an external file
- Have a template of your HTML saved as string literal
- Have the data which you are using stored in a named div when it's rendered

```
const styleData = await fetch('<some_location>/styles.css')
     .then( res => res.text()); // need to convert the file to useable text

const dataHTML = document.getElementById('dataDiv').innerHTML;


const outputHTML = '<html>
    <head>
<style>
    ${styleData }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    ${dataHTML}
</body>';
```

From there you can have your main webpage save the data to a file via button [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file).

Comment: For reasons unknown, it breaks my other code. But I'm working on some code based off yours to work with mine. Thanks though!